# Tool to orchestrate a rolling upgrade

Tags: automation

I develop a product which has several different types of programs running over multiple machines. We are looking for some tool that allows orchestrating a rolling upgrade of these different software components. We require a rolling upgrade since the entire system has to be up at all times, and we need orchestration since we cannot just upgrade any component, the order of upgrading matters and requires making system-wide changes before upgrading a component.

We have our own tool that can orchestrate the upgrade process, but we would like to support the option of upgrading our system using outside tools.

I heard of [Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29), but from what I see, it doesn't allow me to support exact orchestration of the upgrade in a simple way, letting me choose which component is upgraded when.

Are there some other tools or combination of tools that can fulfill my needs?

Free solutions would be best, but I would like to know if there is anything reasonable at all.

Need something that works on both Windows and Linux.